# wp recaptcha wordpress plugin install error

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to install wp-recaptcha in my wordpress site. But it showed me the following error.

```
Warning: require_once(/home2/sample/public_html/test.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-recaptcha/recaptchalib.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/sample/public_html/test.com/wp-content/plugins/wp-recaptcha/recaptcha.php on line 158
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `recaptchalib.php` file is missing in the plugin directory, or that the Web server can not access it. Check you have uploaded all plugin files (since `recaptchalib.php` is present in the plugin package) and that the file permissions are set correctly.